# Vagrant is apparently not merging Vagrantfiles correctly, Chef config is lost

Tags: ruby, vagrant, chef-infra, vagrantfile, vsphere

First off here's the error I'm getting:

```
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

chef client provisioner:
* Chef server URL must be populated.
* Validation key path must be valid path to your chef server validation key.
```

The chef server URL does appear to be populated, and the validation key path is valid.

I've got 3 Vagrantfiles in effect, and I'm using the [documentation](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/index.html) to try to get the order correct.

This works fine when I stick everything in one Vagrantfile in the project directory, but I want to set defaults and not have to copy paste everything.

**1) The Vagrantfile packaged with the box:**

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provider :vsphere do |vsphere|
    vsphere.host = 'vsphereserver.example.com'
    vsphere.compute_resource_name = 'TestDev'
    vsphere.user = 'vagrantadmin'
    vsphere.password = 'password'
    vsphere.insecure = true
  end

  config.ssh.username = 'auto'
  config.ssh.private_key_path = '~/.vagrant.d/id_rsa'
end
```

**2) The Vagrantfile in my home directory (~/.vagrant.d):**

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = 'vsphere'

  config.vm.provider :vsphere do |vsphere|
    vsphere.template_name = 'vagrantchefnode'
  end

  config.vm.provision "chef_client" do |chef|
    chef.add_role "base"
    chef.provisioning_path = "/etc/chef"
    chef.chef_server_url = "https://chefserver.example.com"
    chef.validation_key_path = "/home/user/.vagrant.d/chef/validation.pem"
    chef.client_key_path = "/etc/chef/client.pem"
    chef.validation_client_name = "chef-validator"
    chef.custom_config_path = "/home/user/.vagrant.d/Vagrantfile.chef"
    chef.delete_node = true
    chef.delete_client = true
  end
end
```

**3) Vagrantfile from the project directory (~/.vagrant.d/boxes/chefnode1):**

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.provider :vsphere do |vsphere|
#    vsphere.template_name = 'chefnode'
    vsphere.customization_spec_name = 'chefnode1'
    vsphere.name = 'chefnode1'
  end

  config.vm.provision "chef_client" do |chef|
    chef.node_name = "chefnode1"
    chef.add_role "test"
  end

end
```

Is it overwriting the entire chef_client configuration somehow? If so, how do I make it stick and merge the way it's supposed to?

**Update:**

I've got something working with Tejay's answer and [this doc](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/basic_usage.html), but it requires translating to a different syntax, and I can't figure out how to get methods like `add_role` translated. Here's what I've got:

**2)**

```
  config.vm.provision "chef_client",
    id: "chef",
    provisioning_path: "/etc/chef",
    chef_server_url: "https://chefserver.example.com",
    validation_key_path: "/home/user/.vagrant.d/chef/validation.pem",
    client_key_path: "/etc/chef/client.pem",
    validation_client_name: "chef-validator",
    custom_config_path: "/home/user/.vagrant.d/Vagrantfile.chef",
    delete_node: true,
    delete_client: true
```

**3)**

```
  config.vm.provision "chef_client",
    id: "chef",
    node_name: "chefnode1"
```

So this brings the machine up but I can't specify a run_list.

Comment: Opened a [Github issue](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/4583)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually creating two provisioners, one in each file, and so the provisioner in your project directory does not have a URL or validation key.  Vagrant's documentation explains that you need to use an `id` in order to modify an existing provider.  Take a look at the section "OVERRIDING PROVISIONER SETTINGS" on this page:

https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/basic_usage.html

So try this (not tested):

### The Vagrantfile in my home directory (~/.vagrant.d):

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = 'vsphere'

  config.vm.provider :vsphere do |vsphere|
    vsphere.template_name = 'vagrantchefnode'
  end

  config.vm.provision("chef_client", id: 'someID') do |chef|
    chef.add_role "base"
    chef.provisioning_path = "/etc/chef"
    chef.chef_server_url = "https://chefserver.example.com"
    chef.validation_key_path = "/home/user/.vagrant.d/chef/validation.pem"
    chef.client_key_path = "/etc/chef/client.pem"
    chef.validation_client_name = "chef-validator"
    chef.custom_config_path = "/home/user/.vagrant.d/Vagrantfile.chef"
    chef.delete_node = true
    chef.delete_client = true
  end
end
```

### Vagrantfile from the project directory (~/.vagrant.d/boxes/chefnode1):

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.provider :vsphere do |vsphere|
#    vsphere.template_name = 'chefnode'
    vsphere.customization_spec_name = 'chefnode1'
    vsphere.name = 'chefnode1'
  end

  config.vm.provision("chef_client", id: 'someID') do |chef|
    chef.node_name = "chefnode1"
    chef.add_role "test"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the documentation link. However, when I try this, I get:, in addition to the other errors: `* The following settings shouldn't exist: id` repeated 4 times.

Comment: Hang on, looking like a vagrant [bug](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/3424), I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: Nope, it was fixed in 1.5.3, I'm running 1.6.3

Comment: Ok, it works when I translate it to the syntax given in the doc you linked to, however, I can't figure out how to translate methods like `add_role`, and I'm no good with Ruby...

Comment: @Zook  I'm trying to dig into the source.  I'm sure there is a way to do it without having to switch syntax.  I'll let you know what I find.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I also opened a [github issue](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/4583)

Comment: @Zook, I think I nailed it.  Looks like the id needs to be in the config hash passed to the provision method.  Take a look at my edited answer above.

Comment: `syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'` -- on the comma after "chef_client"

Comment: Well, this got me through that issue, now I have [another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26169872/vagrant-creating-an-incorrect-client-pem-on-chef-node-i-think) :/

Comment: Got a fun little [Heisenbug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26170119/vagrant-vsphere-undefined-method-for-nilnilclass) too if you want to look.