# Vagrant vsphere -- undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, vsphere

This is a really weird heisenbug. Sometimes, when calling `vagrant up`, I get something like this:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'vsphere' provider...
==> default: Calling vSphere CloneVM with the following settings:
==> default:  -- Template VM: COLUMBIA/vm/DirectChannel/vagrantchefnode
==> default:  -- Target VM: COLUMBIA/vm/DirectChannel/dirchantsrv1
==> default: Waiting for SSH to become available...
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

(I forget exactly what the last line looks like, I'm trying to recreate it from the log that was run with the --debug tag.)

Once after I had my Vagrantfiles set up, it did that the first time, and then after `vagrant destroy`, went right on past it with no problem. At one point I had it doing it every single time, so I sent the debug output to a log file. Then I edited the Vagrantfile and it stopped. Then I edited the Vagrant file back to what it was before and it still didn't happen again. I need to know what's causing it so that I can make sure it doesn't happen again.

Here are the lines from the log file which include "nil":

```
DEBUG command:  -- options: {:provider=>nil}
 INFO batch_action: Starting action: #<Vagrant::Machine:0x000000018bb658> up {:destroy_on_error=>true, :parallel=>true, :provision_ignore_sentinel=>false, :provision_types=>nil}
 INFO machine: New machine ID: nil
ERROR warden: Error occurred: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
ERROR warden: Error occurred: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
ERROR warden: Error occurred: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
ERROR warden: Error occurred: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
ERROR vagrant: #<VagrantPlugins::VSphere::Errors::VSphereError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>
ERROR vagrant: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
 INFO interface: error: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
 INFO interface: Machine: error-exit ["VagrantPlugins::VSphere::Errors::VSphereError", "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass"]
```

And here are the Vagrantfiles:

**1) The Vagrantfile packaged with the box:**

```rb
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provider :vsphere do |vsphere|
    vsphere.host = 'vsphereserver.myorg.com'
    vsphere.compute_resource_name = 'TestDev'
    vsphere.user = 'vagrantadmin'
    vsphere.password = 'password'
    vsphere.insecure = true
  end

  config.ssh.username = 'auto'
  config.ssh.private_key_path = '~/.vagrant.d/id_rsa'
end
```

**2) The Vagrantfile in my home directory (~/.vagrant.d):**

```rb
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = 'vsphere'

  config.vm.provider :vsphere do |vsphere|
    vsphere.template_name = 'vagrantchefnode'
  end

  config.vm.provision "chef_client", id: "chef" do |chef|
    chef.provisioning_path = "/etc/chef"
    chef.chef_server_url = "https://chefserver.myorg.com"
    chef.validation_key_path = "/home/user/.vagrant.d/chef/validation.pem"
#    chef.client_key_path = "/etc/chef/client.pem"
    chef.validation_client_name = "chef-validator"
    chef.custom_config_path = "/home/user/.vagrant.d/Vagrantfile.chef"
    chef.delete_node = true
    chef.delete_client = true
    chef.add_role "base"
  end
end
```

**3) Vagrantfile from the project directory (~/.vagrant.d/boxes/chefnode1):**

```rb
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.provider :vsphere do |vsphere|
#    vsphere.template_name = 'chefnode'
    vsphere.customization_spec_name = 'test2'
    vsphere.name = 'test2'
  end

  config.vm.provision "chef_client", id: "chef" do |chef|
    chef.node_name = "test2"
    chef.add_role "dev"
  end
end
```

It feels to me like something is going wrong on the VMware side of things, but I don't have full access on the VMware host. Any ideas?

Comment: I've not used VMware much.  Does vagrant assign the host id, or does vmware do so?  I'm thinking maybe some sort of race condition whereby it asks for a machineid before the id has been assigned.  I'd file a bug report with mitchell (including as much info has you can) and see what he has to suggest.

Comment: Don't know the answer to your question. Not sure whether the bug would be with vagrant or with the vsphere plugin. It turns out the base image was still a running VM and had not been turned back into a template, so it's possible that introduced issues randomly. I'll wait until it happens again before escalating. Thanks for the help.